# Is the Golden Candy's only point being sold?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I safely sell everything marked as “Treasure”?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26877/can-i-safely-sell-everything-marked-as-treasure)

By the name of the item it sounds like some health restoring item, but attempting to select it in the items menu does nothing. Then again, it's the only item I've ever had so far, so I can't tell if I'm doing it wrong anyway.

Aira will buy it for 2.5k pixes and the item *is* described as a treasure, but can this item do more than just that?

Comment: I hate to do this to you, [but this is already answered](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26877/can-i-safely-sell-everything-marked-as-treasure) - all items marked "Treasure" exist only to be sold. Items like Golden Candy are simply meant to give flavor by having multiple types.

Comment: @Grace It's fine, an answer is an answer.